# How can I use Kotlin-Exposed to create a table in a database schema that is not `public` or `dbo` AND create a foreign key on said table?

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

So I'm using Kotlin Exposed to create table for authentication on my `postgresql` db.

This table should be in a dedicated schema in my database, called, let's say: `authentication`, to be simple. All's good, I can define and create the table by using:

```
object UserTable: Table("authentication.user") {
  val id = integer("id").primaryKey().autoIncrement()
  val name = varchar("name", 200)
  val type = integer("type").references(UserTypeTable().id)
}
```

The creation of the table is ok on a different schema, but when it defines the `FK`,  it fails, because it uses the name of the table as suffix for the FK's name.

So it's something like `fk_authentication.user_fk_type_id`, which is a no go, since there cannot be a `.` on the fk's name and I get a syntax error.

```
[main] WARN Exposed - Transaction attempt #0 failed: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Statement(s): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS authentication.user (id INT PRIMARY KEY, "name" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, type INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_authentication.user_fk_type_id FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES authentication.user_type(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
org.jetbrains.exposed.exceptions.ExposedSQLException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
```

> note: I changed the statement to be relatable to the query I wrot:e here as an example. Do not attain to the statement, but to the problem at hand, to correct the syntax.

So I think of 2 possibilities:

- Define table schema in another way, somehow?
- Define FK name explicitely.

Can I do any of those? or should I approach this in another way? 
I'm trying to do both by looking at the `Table.kt` code, but not finding anything that I can use... Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: What Exposed version do you use? It should be fixed in # 0.19.1 and later. See https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/701

Comment: Yeah, I opened the issue on Github on the same date as the question here. Thanks.